# solving trigonometric equation $ \sqrt 2 \sin^2 x+\cos x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sqrt 2 \sin^2 x+\cos x=0$$

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

I tried to do like :

$\sqrt 2 \sin^2 x+\cos x=0/2$.

But can't get anything.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\sqrt 2 \sin^2 x = \sqrt 2(1 - \cos^2 x)$. Make that substitution,

$$\begin{align} \sqrt 2 \sin^2 x + \cos x = 0 & \iff \sqrt 2(1-\cos^2 x) + \cos x = 0\\ \\ &\iff  1 - \cos^2 x + \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\cos x = 0\\ \\ &\iff \cos^2 x - \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\cos x - 1 = 0\end{align}$$

and put $y = \cos x$...You'll have a quadratic equation in $y$ that you can solve.

Comment: √2(1-y^2)+y how to arrange that?

Comment: You can divide through by $\sqrt 2$, and then multiply through by $-1$ to get $$y^2 - \frac 1{\sqrt 2} y - 1 = 0$$. Now you can simply use the quadratic formula to find if and when solutions exist. And for any solution $y = a$, then we know that when $\cos x = a$, we have a solution: $x = \arccos(a)$.